# What causes Directory.GetFiles() to append the given path to the path the program is run from?

Tags: c#

I'm using Directory.GetFiles() to get all the files in a path on a network location.
However I'm running into an issue where it is appending the path I give it to the path that the program is running from.

So,

```
string workingDir = "\\1.1.1.1\c\path\to\directory\"
string dirToSearch "\\1.1.1.1\path\to\search\"
```

But when I run the program Directory.GetFiles(dirToSearch); it searches for files in

```
\\1.1.1.1\c\path\to\directory\1.1.1.1\path\to\search\
```

I've found no cause for this in the documentation or in my searches on Google and I'm not even really sure where to start debugging this.

Comment: Beware escaping: Are you showing the actual values of those strings, or the values as they appear in the debugger? To put it another way, would you write it `@"\\1.1.1.1\path\to\search\"` or `"\\1.1.1.1\path\to\search\"`?

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. Please copy and paste your actual code. You are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: I've just passed a UNC path to Directory.GetFile() and it's done the right thing.  You'd better post the real code and the .NET framework version.  Don't forget the source for the .NET framework is available, and there also various tools to disassemble it if you want to see what's happening internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The path parameter is permitted to specify relative or absolute path
>   information. Relative path information is interpreted as relative to
>   the current working directory

Put double slashes like for each `\` put extra slash so it will be clear that this is absolute network path

Or even simpler, like said in comments below:

```
string dirToSearch @"\\1.1.1.1\path\to\search\"
```

Comment: This was it. I was under the impression I was passing an absolute path, but somewhere in the code I lost my leading slashes.